# как закрыть окно проигрывателя после просмотра видео с помощью Python

Tags: python-3.x

Задача такая - должно запуститься видео, пройти до окончания и окно проигрывателя закрыться автоматически.

Этот код запускает видеопроигрыватель и видео проигрывается.
Но после окончания видео, окно проигрывателя не убирается,если не нажать на красный крестик в правом верхнем углу.
Как сделать,что бы окно проигрывателя исчезало после окончания видео?

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("d:\\file.avi", shell=True)
```

Есть проигрыватель на Python но он даже не проигрывает видео

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.9.0')
import time
import os
import sys
import psutil
import logging

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.video import Video
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.core.window import Window
Config.set('graphics', 'position', 'custom')
Config.set('graphics', 'left', 0)
Config.set('graphics', 'top',  500)
Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', 'False')
#Config.set('graphics', 'borderless',  1)
Config.set('graphics', 'width', 1127)
Config.set('graphics', 'height', 636)

class MyApp(App):

    video = None
    def build(self):
        Window.bind(on_keyboard=self.on_keyboard)  # bind our handler
        self.video = Video(source="f:\\video.mp4")
        self.video.state='play'
        #self.video.options = {'eos': 'loop'}
        self.video.allow_stretch=True
        self.video.pos_hint = {'top': 1.0}
        self.video.bind(eos=self.VideoDone)
        return self.video

    def VideoDone(self, value, value2):
        print ("video done", value, value2)

    def on_stop(self):
        # The Kivy event loop is about to stop, set a stop signal;
        # otherwise the app window will close, but the Python process will
        # keep running until all secondary threads exit.
        print ('stopping and closing kivy')
        #self.video.state='stop'


    def on_keyboard(self, window, key, scancode, codepoint, modifier):
        print (window, key, scancode, codepoint, modifier)
        if codepoint == 'p':
            print ('pausing with p pressed')
            self.video.state='stop'
        if codepoint == 's':
            print ('starting with s pressed')
            self.video.state='play'
        if codepoint == 'r':
            print ('re-starting with r pressed')
            self.video.seek(0, precise=True)




if __name__ == '__main__':
    print ("hi")
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Есть свой проигрыватель на Python. Но он пока даже видео не проигрывает

Answer (score 0):

Вариант 1) юзать либы для работы с плеером 2) юзать pynput эмуляция нажатя клавиш пользователем